# Join Datasets based on row index

Tags: dataset

I would like to join two `Dataset`s based on their row index. Unlike ordinary columns, a row index does not have a name.

## Single Row Index

```
dataSetSingle1=Dataset[{Association["c1"->"a","c2"->1],Association["c1"->"a","c2"->2],Association["c1"->"b","c2"->3],Association["c1"->"b","c2"->4]}][GroupBy["c1"],KeyDrop["c1"]]
```

[image]

```
dataSetSingle2=Dataset[{Association["c1"->"a","c3"->5],Association["c1"->"a","c3"->6],Association["c1"->"b","c3"->7],Association["c1"->"b","c3"->8]}][GroupBy["c1"],KeyDrop["c1"]]
```

[image]

The output I expect is:

[image]

## Multiple Row Indices

To complicate the matter, how would this work for multi-level row indices?

```
dataSetMultiple1=Dataset[{Association["c0"->"M","c1"->"a","c2"->1],Association["c0"->"M","c1"->"a","c2"->2],Association["c0"->"M","c1"->"b","c2"->3],Association["c0"->"M","c1"->"b","c2"->4],Association["c0"->"F","c1"->"x","c2"->5],Association["c0"->"F","c1"->"x","c2"->6],Association["c0"->"F","c1"->"y","c2"->7],Association["c0"->"F","c1"->"y","c2"->8]}][GroupBy["c0"],GroupBy["c1"],KeyDrop["c0"],KeyDrop["c1"]]
```

[image]

Joined with:

```
dataSetMultiple2=Dataset[{Association["c0"->"M","c1"->"a","c3"->9],Association["c0"->"M","c1"->"a","c3"->10],Association["c0"->"M","c1"->"b","c3"->11],Association["c0"->"M","c1"->"b","c3"->12],Association["c0"->"F","c1"->"x","c3"->13],Association["c0"->"F","c1"->"x","c3"->14],Association["c0"->"F","c1"->"y","c3"->15],Association["c0"->"F","c1"->"y","c3"->16]}][GroupBy["c0"],GroupBy["c1"],KeyDrop["c0"],KeyDrop["c1"]]
```

[image]

Note that `Datasets` are hierarchical `Association`s.

```
Normal[dataSetSingle1] (* <|a->{<|c2->1|>,<|c2->2|>},b->{<|c2->3|>,<|c2->4|>}|> *)
Normal[dataSetMultiple1] (* <|M-><|a->{<|c2->1|>,<|c2->2|>},b->{<|c2->3|>,<|c2->4|>}|>,F-><|x->{<|c2->5|>,<|c2->6|>},y->{<|c2->7|>,<|c2->8|>}|> *)
```

Comment: does this work: `{ds1,ds2}=Map[KeyValueMap[<|"rows" -> #,#2|>&]][Transpose@#]&/@{myDataSet1,myDataSet2};
joined=Dataset@JoinAcross[Catenate[Normal@ds1],Catenate[Normal@ds2],"rows"]`?

Comment: No, but I understand your idea: first make 'regular' columns from the indices, then join on those columns, then re-index the output. That's a hack I am trying to avoid (unless there is no more elegant way).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ClearAll[joinDS]

joinDS = Join[##, Depth[Normal@#] - 1] &;

joinDS[dataSetSingle1, dataSetSingle2]

joinDS[dataSetMultiple1, dataSetMultiple2]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, and elegant. Though I'm still disappointed *Datasets*'s internal API cannot deal with joins. Especially once you move to the more general case of *inner joins*, *outer joins*, *left join* and *right join*.

Comment: Note that `joinDS = Join[##, Depth[Normal@#] - 2] &;` works better when there is only a single value per multi-level index (so "M", "a", "c2" gives a single value "1", not a List of {"1", "2"} as in my example above).